# I am trying to add Firebase to my iOS project

Tags: ios

On the official Firebase website there is an instruction - "How to embed Firebase into your application", I tried and stopped at the point where you need to add one line of code, namely `Firebase.configure ()` to the AppDelegate.swift file, but I do not have it in project!
I use swiftUI instead of .storyboard. IOS programming experience is only two days, help a stupid person! [Screenshot Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRhll.png)

Comment: You can solve this with very little research. Just google how to do it or search in so. Research and showing what you have tried is one of the expectations here. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION!** I created an AppDelegate.swift file with this code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return true
    }
}
```

Also added this line to (Your Project Name)App.swift:

```
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).